# Set Visual Studio 2017 error messages to English

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

My Windows 10 on my working machine is set up to German language (I want to leave it that way because of some localization features). I installed VS 2017 in English. But when debugging I get the error messages in german. Which is not so helpful for me while debugging. I also have no .NET Framework (German) installed.

So how to set the error messages to be shown in english?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We use this in our application to show exceptions in English. I can't directly verify it, because my VS is in English as well, but apparently it works for my coworkers who have a German VS. We have set it immediately in our Main():

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```